# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (1049, "Unknown database 'majorproject_db'")

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

iam getting this error even after creating database in mysql i have checked the connection and also database in mysql file. i included this line in app.py

"app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/majorproject_db'"

[this is my phpadmin page where i created my database as majorproject/contact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/danKI.png)

iam not able to find any accurate solutions i read even the documentation part of mysql operational errors but didnt get anything. can anyone plz help me with this issue

Comment: Look at the title bar in your screenshot. It shows `db=majorproject+_db`. You created the database as `majorproject _db` (with a space), not `majorproject_db`.

Answer (score 0):

You have created the database in the PHPMyAdmin named

> majorproject _db

There is a space before _db.

change it to **majorproject_db** issue will be resolved.